# how to upload location data to server ios 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, location, nsurlconnection, cllocationmanager

Hi I am creating plugin which will detect get the location from user and upload it to the server.
when app is in the background it is working very well I am getting new location and it is getting uploaded to the server. But the problem comes after **20-25 mins.** I get the new location update from the device but it is not getting uploaded to the server. I implemented local notification to know whether I am getting the new location or not even I create local notification when that data will get uploaded to the server. but after 25/30 mins I just get notification about new location not for the successful server update. I checked with the server database also.

Whenever I get new location I am storing that in to a local database and for server uploading I am taking that data from database. 
I Read some of the post about  **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler** But it won't work in ios 7 or later. And my app is getting callback in the background so I don't think so **background fetch** also will work in this scenario.Can anyone have implemented something like this? anyone tested it after **25-30 mins**? Help appreciated

Comment: Use significant location change monitoring in the background for location updates across an extended duration.

Comment: yes I am using that. Even I enable the background modes (location updates) from plist. and significant change is useful when my will get killed.

Comment: I have a test app that reports location updates for several days using significant location changes.  It only stops when I delete the app from the device.  It doesn't need ` beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` - just location background mode

Comment: I am getting location update in the background, my problem is after some time (after 25-30 mins) it won't upload data to server.

Comment: Are you still getting location updates when not connected to XCode?  Xcode "kind of" extends the background execution time. You may need to combine background fetch mode with deferred location updates

Comment: Hi Paul, It is working now. actually my network thread was getting garbage value so that reason I was not available to call network function. It is working now. Thanks. :)